# Pandas - How do I save Parquet dataframe to local disc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, save, parquet

Completely new to Python / Pandas. I am not able to download pyarrow, apparently, so I am trying to using the pandas integration to save a parquet file.

My code is like this:

I have a dataframe called df. This data is coming from the MySQL Connector via Panadas and Jupytr Notebook.

I did the code:

> df.to_parquet

It converts it to a parquet, but how can I save this parquet to my local disc? I have tried everything but can't seem to find out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the dataframe stored in memory, you only need to do the following:

```py
df.to_parquet('./file.parquet')
```

The structure is the same as the one for `df.to_csv()`

Comment: Thank you! The error message now seems to be that I don't have fastparquet or pyarrow installed. I have tried installing via pip and conda yet it won't seem to work.

Comment: That must be a problem of your dependencies. Try creating a new environment and reinstalling the libraries. In that way the dependencies will get to work propperly.

Comment: My versions are the following. You can give them a try.
pandas==1.2.5
pyarrow==3.0.0
fastparquet==0.6.3

Comment: Nice! Please, don't forget to mark my answer as correct and upvote it if it helped you :).